# Hive Queries - Count(*), Order by, Sort By not working

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am pretty new to the whole hive, hadoop, spark area

What I have done
Use this wonderfull docker container https://github.com/panovvv/bigdata-docker-compose to interact with hive, hadoop, spark, ....

Now I imported an CSV as a table via the hive console and via beeline
Working fine so far

Plain select * query is working too

But as soon as i use keywords like Order By, Sort by, Count(*) i get a semantic exception

Any ideas

```
hive> select * from sales_records limit 10;
OK
Australia and Oceania   Tuvalu  Baby Food       Offline H       5/28/2010       669165933       6/27/2010       9925   255.28   159.42  2533654.00      1582243.50

select * from sales_records sort by region limit 10;
Query ID = root_20201124135744_7afe7974-90ec-4523-b946-9f6e16f9be41
Total jobs = 1
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create Spark client for Spark session edb4ef00-3af8-4871-ba5a-a4c31436f417)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 30041 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to create Spark client for Spark session edb4ef00-3af8-4871-ba5a-a4c31436f417

hive> select count(*) from sales_records;
Query ID = root_20201124135821_36559999-af26-4daf-82ae-09d41b12b408
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create Spark client for Spark session 9f720f53-6492-4ac6-9ed6-3977abaf8a73)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 30041 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to create Spark client for Spark session 9f720f53-6492-4ac6-9ed6-3977abaf8a73
```

Thanks for your help!
Stefan

Comment: `select *` wont trigger a Spark job but streams data directly from hdfs. But as you can see from console logs, the sort by, order by, count(*) etc does trigger a job and it fails.

You can enable debug logs on client by `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console` and may find more useful logs about why its failing.

Comment: ah did not know that. good hint.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.generateSparkConf(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:140)

i copied all *.jars from spark/jars to hive/libs 
seems to work now, but no idea why this is needed

unfortunately it only works inside the shell in a hive session